# PHP, GD, Image Manipulation

Tags: php, sql, image, gd, imagick

Image Thumbnails and Etc.

Connection to database for the filename and details
The table contains all the real file information.  Mimetype, extensions and etc.

The physical images are located on a hdd in a folder path and are renamed as follow:
s:\onlinemedia\files\1\2241.dat

[Type pjpeg]
[Mime image/jpeg]

I can get all of that information however, when I set header to image/jpg I get the output of my string to the path.

s:\onlinemedia\files\1\2241.dat

```
$fileid = $passcode = '';
$fileid     = (isset($_GET['fileid']) ? $_GET['fileid'] : '');
$passcode   = (isset($_GET['passcode']) ? $_GET['passcode'] :'');
$filename = $frw->source->img($fileid,$passcode);
$thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($filename);
$thumb->adaptiveResize(16,16);
$thumb->save($filename);
$thumb->show($filename);
```

What is really happening here?

Comment: You are going to need to show some code to get any useful answers.

Comment: Yeah, we need the code that retrieves and outputs the file.

Comment: Which and what code would you like the object collection, the method calls or page generation?

Comment: my return data is current as follows:  ÿØÿà�JFIF������ÿþ�/~Ï:/Ákúç‡ô[_èzo‹ ‹[yµû¯„ö~;ÒµŸøjçRµuõ¶âojW>µIk�xaå6M1oý·¿eOÙSà÷Ãm?R›DðOƒ4Ý6OÍá{Ë/øN¸ñeòøÇK¸½¹}?ÁZjxºõô}%á†ù ¶±ˆiMw&ª××}¬tŸ°Ÿuü6Ñ¾<êÔ9Õ>!érN4‰`Šáÿ�èÚÄ·6~šÈK=ßˆu¹`Òe¹µ¿)ok%­º#È"¸K¯×¿Š_²lÿ�¾üKý¤¾/êG‡~ü#ÒžÏÅž>¿ÐSPÕôßÍsacâÍ/IÑôØ5]~/é×í{«FnåÄ›k3}¶Ñ?/£ÂqÌèÔÌr|âXl.çÂÓN5)ÍF*<“Vsv¿*wQNVI·wâÜ^I*Fk•¼N/J?SÅ]rKXó¹¥g¯µü‘ÿÙ

Comment: looks like the headers are wrong

Comment: I thought that too until I looked at the file itself...renamed it to jpg and went to the directory.  It is a jpg in regards to the one requested anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I see in the posted code is this:

```
$thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($filename);
$thumb->adaptiveResize(16,16);
$thumb->save($filename);
$thumb->show($filename);
```

When doing `$thumb-save();` you need to pass the path to a new file to save it as.  How you have it now will overwrite the original if you actually want to do that.  Also, `$thumb->show();` shouldn't need a parameter, it goes off the path parameter you used to create the object to begin with.  I'm also not sure if you need to mess with the headers using PhpThumbFactory, as the show() method handles that I think.

Comment: yes, I had thought that my show parameter was having an issue...and if I provide no path/file parameter to the show then I just get the rendered string rather than a rendered file.

Comment: Maybe there's some issue with overwriting it with save() and then showing it

Comment: no, even with that it has the string output to page as an image...I believe it is because, I am using the file as a .dat the factory isn't able to recognize the correct mimetype/assoc and defaults to rendering the string as image...weird...But, it is the only thing that I can verify.

Comment: Possible, try renaming a .dat to .jpg and trying with that file.

Comment: So, you got the image when you renamed it instead of just the path?  Well, there's your answer then.  You need to rename all the files and change the script that creates them to use the .jpg extension instead of .dat, and refactor the stuff in the database to change the extension (if you have file names saved with the extension in there).  It must use the extension to quickly identify file type.  No reason not to use the actual extension.